# Why are some comments posted using the Instagram API invisible?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Our app allows businesses' Instagram accounts to automatically comment on photos customers post at their location. The comments vary from one app user to the other, and we make sure they are in compliance with Instagram's terms of use. We are always getting a 200 response from the API endpoint that the comments are posted, and can even see the comments count increment, but a lot of times (~30%) those comments are not visible.

[image: Screenshot of comment count showing 1]

[image: Screenshot of post with comments, but the posted comment is not visible]

Comment: Please post some code examples of how you are using the API.

Comment: the comment is posted for the post and is also available via API, but the instagram.com and Instagram app does not show your comment, may be because they think it is spam since you comment "Follow us blah blah..."

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting 'shadowbanned' by IG, which means you (the user) will see the comment but noone else will. This could be a result of spam comment history detected or because the hashtags you are using are on the banned list.